# Exporting to Excel from clipboard and prevent line breaks from adding blank rows

Tags: c#, excel, export-to-excel

When exporting to excel I get blank or multiple rows per data source row when one of my data source cells contains a line break (Carriage Return).  I want to prevent this.

This is the code I am using to create a workbook and paste in my data:

```
//Copy to clipboard
DGVJobList.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableAlwaysIncludeHeaderText;
DGVJobList.SelectAll();
DataObject DO = DGVJobList.GetClipboardContent();
Clipboard.SetDataObject(DO);
DGVJobList.ClearSelection();

//Create Excel Workbook and Paste
Excel.Application XLApp = new Excel.Application();
Excel.Workbook XLWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet XLWorkSheet;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


XLWorkBook = XLApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
XLWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XLWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

Excel.Range XLRange = (Excel.Range)XLWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1];
XLRange.Select();
XLWorkSheet.PasteSpecial(XLRange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the clipboard, you will have more control over data placement by creating a 2D array of data out of your DGVJobList.  Then, create a reference to the Excel Range of the same dimensions and set its value.  This example shows only a generic 2D array for illustration.  You would build your 2D array to lay out your data the way you want.

```
            //Build data as 2D array
        int[,] array2D = new int[,] { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 }, { 7, 8 } };

        //Create Excel Workbook and Paste
        Excel.Application XLApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook XLWorkBook;
        Excel.Worksheet XLWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;


        XLWorkBook = XLApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
        XLWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)XLWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

        //Use range same size as data
        Excel.Range XLRange = (Excel.Range) XLWorkSheet.Range["A1", "B4"];
        XLRange.Value = array2D;
```